# Intellijidea on VM (windows): Giving error Failed to save settings. Please restart Intellijidea. also can not connect to maven central repo

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Have Intellij idea 2020 and installed on VM.

but after opening a project - when we do something (for e.g Build a project) it will start giving this error
Failed to save settings. Please restart Intellijidea.

also unable to connect to maven central repo.
Is there any way where we have to give permission for the user to save settings in idea?

Have checked threads related to this. especially Mark down plugin etc. That doesn't make any difference.

Sharing the link for the logs from Intellijidea
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqc9o2dsujfaqpk/idea.log?dl=0

Comment: i think fro meven you need certificate to be provided , under run / debug configuration -> maven -> Runner tab -> vm option textbox  then -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\certificate

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Comment: @JustTry - Where we can get that certificate?

Comment: @y.bedrov - we can not attach files in stack overflow. if you can share a email id, then I can share with you bcoz to paste, it will be too long.

Comment: You may use any online file sharing service.

Comment: @y.bedrov link for log file. see if you can or anybody else can access and analyze what's happening. Thanks.     https://www88.zippyshare.com/v/zMBMr7O6/file.html

Comment: Sorry, but a lot of ads and additional pages are opened. Could you please use DropBox or other sharing service?

Comment: sharing the link for log file @y.bedrov https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqc9o2dsujfaqpk/idea.log?dl=0

Comment: Thanks! Do you use any antivirus software? Seems there is some problem with access rights: "java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\SBIMF_Automation\.idea\workspace.xml"